# Event handlers when no Taskpane is shown

Tags: office-js

I have an Excel takpane app written using Office javascript API.
It uses addin-commands (buttons on the ribbon), and most of the functionality is accomplished without displaying the Taskpane. Taskpane is displayed only in a few cases.

I have event handlers for selectionChanged and dataChanged. I am able to add the event handlers. But I also need to remove and add the handlers multiple times, for example, when loading data into the worksheet.

The documentation / code that I've seen seen accomplishes this by storing the event handlers in a variable on some object in the taskpane page. But in my case, since there is no taskpane page to hold eventhandlers in a variable, and since the javascript in the FunctionFile page executes on each button click and goes out of scope, how do I create/remove/re-create event handlers?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Could you link to the documentation / code that you mention, so I can get a better idea of what you mean by "storing the event handlers"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that event handlers currently have a dependency on having a piece of code (e.g. a Taskpane) already running. There is currently no ability to respond to events without a visible taskpane. This functionality is on the backlog however. I don't have an ETA to share though.